NestJS Mongoose - populate doesn't work for array with references
This is my Schema
@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
})
export class Fridge {
  @Prop({
    default: () => uuidv4(),
  })
  _id: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  user: string;

  @Prop({ type: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }] })
  products: Types.ObjectId[];

  @Prop({
    type: Date,
    default: null,
  })
  deletedAt: string;
}

I want to return all fridges with products and this is how my query looks like:
async getFridgeData(userId: string): Promise<Fridge[]> {
    return this.fridgeModel.find().populate('products').exec();
  }

Unfortunatly it doesn't work, I always get products as array with string instead of dereferenced value.
Thanks for assist!

Is the response truly an array of strings? Or an array of objectIds? Please also show where you import Types from. Is it mongoose.Types or mongoose.Schema.Types?
